# Arabic to Roman Converter

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a Arabic decimal to roman converter with + - function . But not able to get the desired result . For example 596+535=1131 so in the roman text box it should show it as DLXXXXVI + DXXXV= MCXXXI but not able to get it . Have tried using while loop and math.floor but do not know where i am wrong .Please if possible help me out :)

```
Private Sub Btnplus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnplus.Click
    txtroman.Text = ""
    Txtromanappear.Text = ""
    txtarabic.Text = ""

    'Read number1
    num1 = Txtnum1.Text
    'Read number2
    num2 = Txtnum2.Text
    'sum1=num1+num2
    sum1 = num1 + num2
    'output=sum1
    txtarabic.Text = sum1
    If (num1 <= 10) Then
        Select Case num1
            Case 1
                Txtromanappear.Text = "I"
            Case 2
                Txtromanappear.Text = "II"
            Case 3
                Txtromanappear.Text = "III"
            Case 4
                Txtromanappear.Text = "IIII"
            Case 5
                Txtromanappear.Text = "V"
            Case 6
                Txtromanappear.Text = "VI"
            Case 7
                Txtromanappear.Text = "VII"
            Case 8
                Txtromanappear.Text = "VIII"
            Case 9
                Txtromanappear.Text = "VIIII"
            Case 10
                Txtromanappear.Text = "X"
                romanappear = Txtromanappear.Text

        End Select

    ElseIf (num1 > 5) Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(num1 / 5)
        While (sum2 > 0)
            Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "V"

            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While

        sum2 = num1 Mod 5
    End If
    If (num1 > 10) Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(num1 / 10)
        While (sum2 > 0)
            Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "X"

            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        sum2 = num1 Mod 5

    End If




    If (num1 > 50) Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(num1 / 50)
        While (sum2 > 0)
            Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "L"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        sum2 = num1 Mod 50
    End If

    If (num1 > 100) Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(num1 / 100)
        While (sum2 > 0)
            Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "C"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        sum2 = num1 Mod 100
    End If
    If (num1 > 500) Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(num1 / 500)
        While (sum2 > 0)
            Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "D"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        sum2 = num1 Mod 500
    End If
    If (num1 > 1000) Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(num1 / 1000)
        While (sum2 > 0)
            Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "M"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        sum2 = num1 Mod 1000
    End If


    Select Case sum2
            Case 1
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "I"
            Case 2
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "II"
            Case 3
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "III"
            Case 4
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "IIII"
            Case 5
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "V"
            Case 6
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VI"
            Case 7
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VII"
            Case 8
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VIII"
            Case 9
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VIIII"
            Case 10
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "X"
        End Select





        If (num2 <= 10) Then
        Select Case num2
            Case 1
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "+ " + "I"
            Case 2
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "+ " + "II"
            Case 3
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "+ " + "III"
            Case 4
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + " +" + "IIII"
            Case 5
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + " +" + "V"
            Case 6
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + " +" + "VI"
            Case 7
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + " +" + "VII"
            Case 8
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "+ " + "VIII"
            Case 9
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + " +" + "VIIII"
            Case 10
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + " +" + "X"
                romanappear = Txtromanappear.Text

        End Select
    ElseIf (num2 > 10) Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(num2 / 10)
        Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "+"

        While (sum2 > 0)
            Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "X"

            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        sum2 = num2 Mod 10
        Select Case sum2
            Case 1
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "I"
            Case 2
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "II"
            Case 3
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "III"
            Case 4
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "IIII"
            Case 5
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "V"
            Case 6
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VI"
            Case 7
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VII"
            Case 8
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VIII"
            Case 9
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "VIIII"
            Case 10
                Txtromanappear.Text = Txtromanappear.Text + "X"
                romanappear = Txtromanappear.Text
        End Select

    End If

    If sum1 <= 10 Then
        Select Case sum1
            Case 1
                txtroman.Text = "I"
            Case 2
                txtroman.Text = "II"
            Case 3
                txtroman.Text = "III"
            Case 4
                txtroman.Text = "IIII"
            Case 5
                txtroman.Text = "V"
            Case 6
                txtroman.Text = "VI"
            Case 7
                txtroman.Text = "VII"
            Case 8
                txtroman.Text = "VIII"
            Case 9
                txtroman.Text = "VIIII"
            Case 10
                txtroman.Text = "X"


        End Select

    ElseIf sum1 > 10 Then
        sum2 = Math.Floor(sum1 / 10)
        While (sum2 > 0)
            txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "X"

            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        sum2 = sum1 Mod 10
        Select Case sum2
            Case 1
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "I"
            Case 2
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "II"
            Case 3
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "III"
            Case 4
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "IIII"
            Case 5
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "V"
            Case 6
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "VI"
            Case 7
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "VII"
            Case 8
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "VIII"
            Case 9
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "VIIII"
            Case 10
                txtroman.Text = txtroman.Text + "X"
        End Select

    End If
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  Fix errors. Give a better problem description than the vague `not able to get the desired result`

Comment: Ok sorry if you were not able to get what i meant. 
I have 5 txt boxes . 
1.Num1 ( Enter First number)
2.num2   (Enter Second Number)
3.arabic decimal ( Result of NUm 1 +NUm2)
4.roman appear( It show the working 65+45 in roman appear should be LV+XXXV)
5.roman ( Here it will show the sum of both numbers in roman.
  If i have to add two numbers 65 + 45 so the result in arabic decimal should be 110 and in roman it should be LXV+XXXXV 
But what i get is this VVVVVVVVVVVVVXXXXXXL+XXXXV in roman appear. 
I cannot figure out what should be the method or code to get it right
Appreciate yourrsponse:)

Comment: As an aside, I believe 4 in Roman numerals is IV not IIII

Comment: @FarhanTariq:  The ordering of the numbers isnt always largest to smallest, so your conversion logic needs to be a lot more complicated. For example, 9 would be IX and 99 are written as XCIX (10-100 1-9) To be honest, I would scrap what you have and start again after looking at how the romans actually wrote  roman numerals. Sorry. Personally, I would write a routine to generate an array of all the numbers up to 1000 in roman, and use it as to lookup numbers rather than use logic to convert it.

Comment: @David Wilson Thanks for the reply and i am totally aware of what you mentioned but i have been told not to do it that way and to keep it simple.

Comment: @DavidWilson but that would be hard code . To assign every integer with a roman numeral and that would take long and there would be no logic and i am supposed to use a logic in order to get the program done . But not able to figure out exactly what

Comment: heh - Ok :) Tho - ignoring the ix and xc stuff, a small lookup table would be much simpler. Personal opinion :) - OK I'll have a look and see if i can spot anything - if I dont reply - its only because I cant find the problem.

Comment: @peterG  it has to be written as IIII because it is required to be like that :)

Comment: OK getting there firstly the order of your If statements is the wrong way round. yo should be finding the thousands first, the 500's next and so on. Also for each time you find say a thousand, as well as taking 1 from the sum, you should take 1000 from num1 and in the next group, you should take 500 from num1 for each 500 you find - although of course, you will only ever find one 500, so that code could possibly be rewritn without a while loop.. anyway, im working through it. ill be back in a while

Comment: @DavidWilson Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've re-ordered  your code so that you start adding the biggest roman numerals  first and changed the line

```
sum2=num1 mod 1000
```

to

```
num1=num1 mod 100
```

so that num1 gets passed down through the if statements properly

I've only rewritten the code that handles num1 so that you can.. either - apply the same to the code that handles num2, but I dont know if you want to do that as you may have been asked to code the handling of num2 differently - In which case, you can apply the same principles to the select case statements anyway - test for the biggest Roman numerals first

Also - the IF statements should test num1 for being >= to 1000 etc because if num1 equals exactly 1000, that block wont execute  and messes up the subsequent IF..End IF blocks

```
     If (num1 >= 1000) Then
        sum2 = CInt(Math.Floor(num1 / 1000))
        While (sum2 > 0)
            txtRomanAppear.Text = txtRomanAppear.Text + "M"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        num1 = num1 Mod 1000
    End If

    If (num1 >= 500) Then
        sum2 = CInt(Math.Floor(num1 / 500))
        While (sum2 > 0)
            txtRomanAppear.Text = txtRomanAppear.Text + "D"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        num1 = num1 Mod 500
    End If

    If (num1 >= 100) Then
        sum2 = CInt(Math.Floor(num1 / 100))
        While (sum2 > 0)
            txtRomanAppear.Text = txtRomanAppear.Text + "C"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        num1 = num1 Mod 100
    End If

    If (num1 >= 50) Then
        sum2 = CInt(Math.Floor(num1 / 50))
        While (sum2 > 0)
            txtRomanAppear.Text = txtRomanAppear.Text + "L"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        num1 = num1 Mod 50
    End If

    If (num1 >= 10) Then
        sum2 = CInt(Math.Floor(num1 / 10))
        While (sum2 > 0)
            txtRomanAppear.Text = txtRomanAppear.Text + "X"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        num1 = num1 Mod 10
    End If

    If (num1 >= 5) Then
        sum2 = CInt(Math.Floor(num1 / 5))
        While (sum2 > 0)
            txtRomanAppear.Text = txtRomanAppear.Text + "V"
            sum2 = sum2 - 1
        End While
        num1 = num1 Mod 5
    End If

    'for the remaining digits <5, just create a string of i's eg if num1=4 then add a string of 4 i's
    If (num1 > 0) Then
        For i = 1 To num1
            txtRomanAppear.Text=txtRomanAppear.Text+"I"
        Next
    End If


    'This IF block can be removed as it's no longer needed
    'If (num1 < 10) Then
    '    Select Case num1
    '        Case 1
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "I"
    '        Case 2
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "II"
    '        Case 3
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "III"
    '        Case 4
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "IIII"
    '        Case 5
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "V"
    '        Case 6
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "VI"
    '        Case 7
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "VII"
    '        Case 8
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "VIII"
    '        Case 9
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "VIIII"
    '        Case 10
    '            txtRomanAppear.Text = "X"
    '            romanAppear = txtRomanAppear.Text

    '    End Select
```

To make all that code more compact, you could write a couple of functions, as there is an awful lot of code repetition. Hope this helps. If you have any problems let me know. If this works for you, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted :-)

Bed time here.

Comment: thanks for that mate.  Will update you once i get on with it . Cheers

Comment: Yes it does works :) Happy Days :) Thanks mate Appreciate it

Comment: No Problem. Here to help where I can